# how to control read/write pointer in lock-free ringbuffer?

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

I just write a lock-free ringbuffer dem, but works failed with multi reader threads. In my code, the read and write pointers are incremented. I can't guarantee that the read pointer will always be after the write pointer.

This is my put/get function:

```
template<class T>
bool RingBuffer<T>::put( const T& node )
{
    // local the avaliable place
    while ( full() ) {
        if ( !waitForFull() ) return false;
    }

    ::std::size_t pos = m_front.fetch_add(1);
    while( !__sync_bool_compare_and_swap( &m_statusBuffer[ locate(pos) ], NS_WRITEABLE, NS_WRITEPENDING ) ) {
        if ( m_statusBuffer[ locate(pos) ] == NS_READPENDING ) {
            // wait for read complete
            continue;
        }

        while ( full() ) {
            if ( !waitForFull() ) return false;
        }

        pos = m_front.fetch_add(1);
    }
    fprintf( stderr, "put pos: %ld, front: %ld, rear: %ld\n", pos, m_front.load(), m_rear.load() );

    // update data
    m_circularBuffer[ locate(pos) ]   = node;
    m_statusBuffer[ locate(pos) ]     = NS_READABLE;

    return true;
}

template<class T>
::std::tuple<T, bool> RingBuffer<T>::get()
{   
    while ( empty() ) {
        if ( !waitForEmpty() ) return ::std::make_tuple( T(), false );
    }

    // local the avaliable place
    ::std::size_t pos = m_rear.fetch_add(1);
    while( !__sync_bool_compare_and_swap( &m_statusBuffer[ locate(pos) ], NS_READABLE, NS_READPENDING ) ) {
        if ( m_statusBuffer[ locate(pos) ] == NS_WRITEPENDING ) {
            // wait for write complete
            continue;
        }

        while ( empty() ) {
            if ( !waitForEmpty() ) return ::std::make_tuple( T(), false );
        }

        pos = m_rear.fetch_add(1);
    }
    fprintf( stderr, "get pos: %zd, front: %ld, rear: %ld\n", pos, m_front.load(), m_rear.load() );

    // update value
    auto ret = m_circularBuffer[ locate(pos) ];
    m_statusBuffer[ locate(pos) ]   = NS_WRITEABLE;

    return ::std::make_tuple( ret, true );
}
```

and the empty / full is :

```
template<class T>
bool RingBuffer<T>::empty()
{
    return ( m_rear.load() >= m_front.load() );
}

template<class T>
bool RingBuffer<T>::full()
{
    //return ( ( m_front.load() >= m_rear.load() && ( m_front.load() - m_rear.load() ) >= m_mask ) );
    return ( m_front.load() - m_rear.load() ) >= m_mask );
}
```

When I use multi threads, the read pointer will step over write pointer, then block or core dump.

How can I fix this bug?

Comment: In a lock-free ringbuffer it's possible to synchronize between the writer and the reader. That's usually done by comparing the write and read pointer (or index), while  only the writer may change the write pointer and the reader may change only the read pointer. What mechanism do you plan to synchronize multiply readers with a lock-free access? I would say the concept is weird or at least unclear.

Comment: I add a extra status buffe for multi writers to write at the same time, it also affects the read operation. But it brings a lot of bugs.Thanks for your answer.I wiil try to completely separate readers and writers.

Comment: Mixing `std::atomic` with legacy `__sync` builtins shouldn't be necessary. I suggest learning from the best examples, e.g. https://github.com/max0x7ba/atomic_queue